# Send Web Push Notification using PHP CURL

Tags: php, php-curl, web-push

I wanted to use PHP CURL to send push notification.

Here's my sample payload

```
$payload = [
    'title' => 'Web Push',
    'body' => 'Hello World and Web Push',
    'icon' => 'assets/icons/logo.png',
    'data' => ['url' => 'https://mywebapp.com']
];
```

Here's my VAPID Keys

```
$auth = [
    'VAPID' => [
        'subject' => 'mailto:myemail@gmail.com',
        'publicKey' => 'VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY',
        'privateKey' => 'VAPID_PRIVATE_KEY',
    ]
];
```

Here's a sample push subscription data

```
$subscription = [
    'endpoint' => "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/some_endpoint",
    'keys' => [
        'auth' => "some_auth_key",
        'p256dh' => "some_p256dh_key"
    ]
];
```

Here's my function to send using curl but I don't know how to generate the headers

```
public function sendPushNotification($subscription, $payload, $auth) {
    // initialize curl
    $curl = curl_init();

    // Set the request URL
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $subscription['endpoint']);

    // Set the request headers
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: WebPush',
        'Crypto-Key: '
    ]);

    // Set the request method
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    // Set the request body
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($payload));

    // Return the response instead of outputting it directly
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Execute the cURL request
    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    // Check for errors
    if ($response === false) {
        $error = curl_error($curl);
        echo 'cURL error: ' . $error;
    } else {
        echo 'Web push notification sent successfully!';
    }

    // Close the cURL session
    curl_close($curl);

    return $response;
}
```

Does anyone know how to generate the headers and make this work?

Comment: Generate what headers? How is it currently _not_ working?

Comment: @Phil, I'm not sure yet what to put on CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/web-push-interop-wins/#sending-a-push-message could help

Comment: @Kazz, do you know how to do it with PHP?